# Resultset is slow for oracle ref cursor

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle12c

Getting a cursor result set from procedure and iterating it is much slower than query result set. I have a procedure which returns a cursor but it took 5s to fetch the next result set.

```
String callProcedure = "{ call SCHEMANAME.TEMP_PACKAGE.GET_CURSOR_RESULTS(?,?,?,?) }"; 
cs = con.prepareCall(callProcedure);
cs.setString(1, "Variable1");
cs.setString(2,"Variable2");
cs.setString(3,"Variable3");
cs.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR); 
ResultSet  rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(4);           

while (rs.next()){ 
}
```

I have used logs and found that rs.next() get 5-6 seconds. 
So I have changed the logic as below,

```
String callProcedure = "{ call SCHEMANAME.TEMP_PACKAGE.GET_CURSOR_RESULTS(?,?,?,?,?) }"; 
cs = con.prepareCall(callProcedure);
cs.setString(1, "Variable1");
cs.setString(2,"Variable2");
cs.setString(3,"Variable3");
cs.registerOutParameter(4,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
cs.registerOutParameter(5,java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

I got those parameters from the procedure and use a preparedStatement to execute the query which was used in the cursor.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()){ 
}
```

Above approach is faster than using a sys_refcursor. Please explain why using sys_refcursor taking much time than a normal query.

PS: Cursor will not return more than 20 rows.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the time to execute the procedure with `SYS_REFCURSOR` from the database?

Answer (score 0):

this should be helpful

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621

> By default, when Oracle JDBC runs a query, it retrieves a result set
>   of 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. This is the default
>   Oracle row fetch size value. You can change the number of rows
>   retrieved with each trip to the database cursor by changing the row
>   fetch size value.

Statement, PreparedStatement, CallableStatement, and ResultSet objects for setting and getting the fetch size:

```
void setFetchSize(int rows) throws SQLException

int getFetchSize() throws SQLException
```

Comment: In this case , I have already tried fetchSize and it doesn't helps.